# Display distinct users reaching specific count thresholds

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Here's my table, showing user names and the timestamp they scored a point:

```
id  user    date
1   Aaron   23/02/2012 22:44
2   Betty   23/02/2012 22:47
3   Carlos  24/02/2012 16:01
4   David   28/02/2012 11:40
5   David   28/02/2012 12:32
6   David   28/02/2012 16:59
7   Aaron   2/03/2012 13:46
8   Aaron   30/03/2012 18:37
9   Betty   30/03/2012 19:58
10  Emma    9/04/2012 6:49
11  Emma    9/04/2012 13:19
12  Emma    9/04/2012 18:20
13  Emma    9/04/2012 20:46
14  Aaron   10/04/2012 15:47
15  Betty   10/04/2012 19:15
16  Betty   10/04/2012 20:40
17  Carlos  11/04/2012 9:44
18  Carlos  11/04/2012 20:01
19  David   11/04/2012 23:17
20  David   12/04/2012 17:09
```

And here is the results table I am *trying* to achieve, i.e. an x axis showing month-year, and a y axis displaying the number of users who reached a certain points threshold *within that month*:

```
date    1 point First time? 2 points    First time? 3 points    First time? 4 points    First time?     Total
Feb-12  A,B,C   A,B,C                               D           D                                       4
Mar-12  B                   A           A                                                               3
Apr-12  A,B,C               B,C,D       B,C,D                               E           E               4
```

I've only got as far as calculating the total number of points and the total number of distinct scorers within a given month:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT (MONTHNAME(date), ' ', YEAR(date)) as 'date', COUNT(id) as total_points, COUNT(distinct referrer_id) as number_of_scorers
from points
group by CONCAT (MONTH(date), ' ', YEAR(date))
order by YEAR(date), MONTH(date)
```

which is only giving me:

```
date    total_points    number_of_scorers
Feb-12  6               4
Mar-12  3               3
etc.
```

So my questions are:

1. How can I amend the query to show me which users reached each point threshold within each month?
2. How can I amend the query to show me which users reached each point threshold *for the first time* within that month?

Thanks

Comment: What is "A", "B", "C" and so on?  Do they somehow relate to the sample data you have provided?

Comment: Apologies - they're just shortnames of the users (A = Aaron etc.)

Answer (score 0):

The basic query you need is this:

```
select date_format(date, '%Y-%m') as yyyymm, user, count(*) as points
from t
group by date_format(date, '%Y-%m') as yyyymm, user;
```

This gets the number of points for each user in a month.

The rest is just aggregations, joins, and conditions:

```
select ymu.yyyymm,
       group_concat(case when ymu.points = 1 then user end) as Points1_Users,
       group_concat(case when ymu.points = 1 and ymu.yyyymm = u.min_yyyymm then user end) as Points1_Users_First,
       group_concat(case when ymu.points = 2 then user end) as Points2_Users,
       group_concat(case when ymu.points = 2 and ymu.yyyymm = u.min_yyyymm then user end) as Points2_Users_First
from (select date_format(date, '%Y-%m') as yyyymm, user, count(*) as points
      from t
      group by date_format(date, '%Y-%m') as yyyymm, user
     ) ymu join
     (select user, min(yyyymm) as min_yyyymm
      from (select date_format(date, '%Y-%m') as yyyymm, user, count(*) as points
            from t
            group by date_format(date, '%Y-%m') as yyyymm, user
           ) t
      group by user
     ) u
     on ymu.user = u.user
group by yyyymm
order by yyyymm;
```

Comment: Great, thanks for this - works brilliantly, though I had to add this to the end of temp table t to give me more than one _PointsX_User_first_ result :
`) t group by yyyymm, user)`